# Synonym for "repartition" with the notion of "continuous"

Tags: synonyms

Here's a sentence I'm trying to improve:

*"This diagram represents the **repartition** of methods throughout the phases of the project"*

Supposing there isn't a *1 to 1* distribution of methods and phases, but rather a continuous gradient (method A is more intensely used in the beginning, less in the end, method B more used in the end, less in beginning, etc), is there a better word than repartition or distribution to convey this *continuous* notion?

Comment: Maybe "reallocation".

Comment: I certainly don't think ***repartition*** works in your context. You could consider ***reassignment, reallocation, redistribution,*** etc., but I can't see how anything like that would convey your "continuous" sense (which is far too subtle for me to understand, even with the benefit of your final "explanatory" paragraph).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It could be described as a _**continuous redistribution**_ or a _**smooth redistribution**_ though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would accept a suggestion on how to improve the sentence through restructuring rather than with a synonym, how about:

> "This diagram shows the relative use of methods at each project
>   phase, illustrating the shift in emphasis from Method A to Method B."

I like this construction because it starts by explaining how to read the figure before going on to suggest how to interpret that data.

Comment: ah thanks! very helpful, the out-of-the-box answer is much appreciated and works better than a synonym in my text, in fact!

Answer (score 0):

**Repartition** in this context may indicate that the original document was written by a [French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9partition) speaker, and used on the premise that words ending in "ion" are usually the same in both English and French.  Just change it to **distribution** and move on.  It's the diagram that matters most to the reader. Effort spent on tweaking the surrounding words usually has a pretty low return.

Comment: Very insightful, thanks for the remark: i indeed falsely assumed the meaning in English was exactly the same, apparently not quite. Anyway my question was more out of curiosity than trying to optimize the "return" of my paragraph, so all comments were welcome.